# htaccess redirect all content including subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 3 domains, for the same web app, since I don't want to have duplicated content I want to redirect the other two domains to the primary domain.

If a user types `client_xyz.domain2.com` it should be redirected to `client_xyz.primarydomain.com`.

If a user types `client_xyz.domain2.com/folder/file/etc` it should be redirected to `client_xyz.primarydomain.com/folder/file/etc`.

If a user types `domain2.com/test/page`  it should be redirected to `primarydomain.com/test/page`

I thought this is the best solution to avoid Google penalty for duplicated content.
If you think there's a better solution to deal with this (eg. DNS), let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(client_xyz\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1primarydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: To have variable client_xyz, use something like: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: Thanks @Gerben, it is indeed possible but OP needs to be aware that it will also redirect something like `admin.domain2.com` to `admin.primarydomain.com` which may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can user regex in the .htaccess file, so set up a 301 (moved permanently) redirect.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (^.*?\.|^)domain2.com(.*) $1.primarydomain.com$2
```

Untested, but should be fine.

[edit]The below is fairly useless since your comment, but I'll leave it here anyway.

Alternatively, you could set up server alias's in your Apache config file. You probably have something like this:

```
ServerName primarydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Change it to:

```
ServerName primarydomain.com
ServerAlias domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/
<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: client_xyz is a variable too. It can be client_xyz, client_123. client_test.

Comment: Okay, see edit. Make sure you test it first, though, because I'm not a regex expert and that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: I dont have access to apache config file.
Your htaccess gives me a 500 Error

Comment: Sorry man, the formatting got messed up. Remove the line breaks so it's all one line. Note that I've made a few changes to make it more robust.

Comment: I'm sorry but still doesn't work. I dont get the 500 error anymore, it just does nothing.

Comment: /facepalm That's because I'm being stupid, and redirectmatch works using directories, not Internet addresses. Bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use mod_rewrite, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^.*?\.|^)?domain2\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.primarydomain.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

If not, well, I'm probably going to have to leave it up to someone smarter than me ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work when file of directory exists, so you should remove the 2nd and 3rd rewritecond. Also it only works for root folders, not on any subfolders, or the root itself, or any files in the root. nubhava's answer seems ok.